# Is it possible to access the solution array at every time step using solve_ivp?

Tags: python, scipy

I'm using `solve_ivp` from `scipy.integrate` to solve a system of equations given by,

`Xdot = A*X + B*U` where`X`is an array of size `4*1`.

```
def func(t,X):        
    Xdot=A*X+B*U
    return Xdot
```

And using the solver as

```
solv = solve_ivp(convf, tspan,Z0,method='BDF')
time_value=solv.t
solution_array=sol.y
```

Is it possible to access the solution array `solution_array` at every time step corresponding to `time_value`for any manipulation while the solver is runnig during `tspan`

Comment: From the docs it looks as though you can pass your `time_value` as an array using the keyword `t_eval` and the solver will return the solution value at each point in `time_value`. So for every time step add the argument `t_eval=tspan` to the function. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html

Comment: Then how do I access it?Could you make the changes in the above code?

Answer (score 0):

The `t_eval` argument allows you to get the solution for different time points.

An example from the docs:

```
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
def exponential_decay(t, y): return -0.5 * y 

sol = solve_ivp(exponential_decay, [0, 10], [2, 4, 8])

sol.t
>>> array([ 0.        ,  0.11487653,  1.26364188,  3.06061781,  4.81611105,
    6.57445806,  8.33328988, 10.        ])
```

The solver returns appears arbitrary time points by default. So by adding the `t_eval` argument to get solutions at user defined time points:

```
t = np.linspace(0, 10, 50)
sol = solve_ivp(exponential_decay, [0, 10], [2, 4, 8], t_eval=t)

sol.t == t
>>> True
```

And the solutions at time points `sol.t` are accessed by `sol.y` as before.

Comment: This is fine. But my question is to get the solutions at time points defined by the solver only.But I want them at each time point while the simulation is going on.